# How can i improve this website performance?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, optimization, html5-video

This is my first time asking a question here on stackoverflow.

I'd like to know if anyone (more experienced in web design than me, but that's an easy one!) can help me out with a couple tips on how to make this website faster to load and navigate:

[www.treasure-diggers.com](http://www.treasure-diggers.com/)

I know the HD video banner is the first thing that comes to mind, but that was an explicit request from the client (no Low-Definition render or Youtube player).

Aside from that, it's just a wordpress page with a dozen of medium-sized images, and yet it takes quite a while to load on low connection speeds.

Do you have any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: not a programming question so should not be posted in this forum. Try another forum on stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, I've checked your website in website speed test service (GTmetrix) and [here you can check the result yourself](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.treasure-diggers.com/anYxiTTm).

There are some advices, for example, you can minify CSS and JS files and you can specify image dimensions for small images, like social icons, for example. try to resize big images yourself, not with the help of website. After that check the result in GTmetrix, your website speed will be improved =)

Comment: amazing! thank you very much!

Comment: If you like my answer, please approve it =)